# One Connection to Server - download several Images

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, httpconnection

When downloading images from a server I wonder if the following code could be improved so that I only make ONE connection (handshake) with the server (host) and after that downloading images from that server - one by one ?

Look at the code

String imageUrl = https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//jjPJ4s3DWZZvI4vw8Xfi4Vqa1Q8.jpg

```
        URL imgUrl = new URL(imageUrl);
                            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) imgUrl.openConnection();
                            httpURLConnection.connect();
                            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                            Bitmap movieBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

This is made in a loop in AsyncTask so the full url here is the first file/image that is fetched from the server. Then in the next loop the path on the server to the filename is changed to a new image.

The problem here is that a connection is made at EACH loopstep - so if there is 10 iterations there are 10 connections since I have to make a connection to every image.

So the question is if I could break up the full url-path to

- host (that is ONE connection to **https://image.tmdb.org**)
- after the connection is made, add the rest, which means where the image is located on the server (in this case: **/t/p/w500//jjPJ4s3DWZZvI4vw8Xfi4Vqa1Q8.jpg**) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Retrofit, here u can add a base URL and then dynamically change the remaining url